# Get attribute value from XML file

Tags: node.js, xml, xpath, opc-ua

I am trying to retrieve from an OPCUA NodeSet all the NodeIds of UAObjectType.

Here It is the xml file: https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-Nodeset/blob/master/Robotics/Opc.Ua.Robotics.NodeSet2.xml

This is the code I am using:

```
 NodeName = select("//ns1:UAObjectType/ns1:DisplayName/text()", ns);
  NodeId = select(String("//ns1:UAObjectType/@NodeId") , ns);
  fs.writeFileSync("Names.xml" , NodeName )
  fs.writeFileSync("Ids.xml", NodeId)
  console.log(NodeId);
  if (mapper["ObjectType"] != null) {
    var otypes = {};
    for (i = 0 ; i<NodeName.length ; i++){
        add(otypes , NodeName[i] , NodeId[i]);
    }
  }
```

This is what I get as output in the Ids.xml file:

```
 NodeId="ns=1;i=1001", NodeId="ns=1;i=15035", NodeId="ns=1;i=15048", NodeId="ns=1;i=15051"
```

This is what I would like to have as output:

```
ns=1;i=1001, ns=1;i=15035 , ns=1;i=15048 , ns=1;i=15051
```

Do you know how can I solve it?

Thanks everybody for the attention.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have access to an XPath 2.0 processor (Saxon-JS ?, xpath.js ?) :

```
string-join(//*[name()="UAObjectType"]/@NodeId,",")
```

Test with : https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OPCFoundation/UA-Nodeset/master/Robotics/Opc.Ua.Robotics.NodeSet2.xml

Output : `'ns=1;i=1002,ns=1;i=1004,ns=1;i=16601,ns=1;i=16794,ns=1;i=1019,ns=1;i=1022,ns=1;i=1013,ns=1;i=17230,ns=1;i=17233,ns=1;i=1003,ns=1;i=17725,ns=1;i=17793,ns=1;i=1011,ns=1;i=1018,ns=1;i=18175'`

Or with XPath 1.0, loop over each `UAObjectType` and concat each string of `@NodeId` (`string(./@NodeId)`).